# What do I need to input in the property of the Container that can fit to screen to a different phones?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is the error when i'm trying to put fit to screen code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXHpV.png

here's my container code:

> ```
>  Container( 
>           color: Colors.grey[700],
>           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
>           width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
>           child: Icon(Icons.home, size: 100.0,),
>         )
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your container in a SingleChildScrollView widget like this:

```
 SingleChildScrollView (
    child:
        Container( 
        
                  color: Colors.grey[700],
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Icon(Icons.home, size: 100.0,),
                )
    )
```

also if ur container is a child of a column or a row you can wrap that row or column in an expanded widget.